# Submitting Contact Form with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, contacts

I have a contact form, which I want to submit with AJAX, because I want the echo Messages from the PHP file to show directly under my contact form.

Thats what i got:

form.php

```
<form id="ContactForm" action="contact.php" method="POST" enctype="text">
    <table class="contact-form">
        <tr>
            <td>Name<font color="#d25911">*</font></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="betreff" name="betreff" placeholder="Betreff" size="45"/>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Max Mustermann" size="45"/>                            
            </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>E-Mail<font color="#d25911">*</font></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="max@mustermann.de" value="" size="45"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>Telefon:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="telefon" name="telefon" placeholder="Optional" size="45"/></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>Nachricht<font color="#d25911">*</font></td>
            <td>
                <textarea id="nachricht2" name="nachricht2" placeholder="Ihre Nachricht"></textarea>
                <textarea id="nachricht1" name="nachricht1" placeholder="Ihre Nachricht"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <center>
                    <input type="submit" value="Senden" id="submit" name ="submit">
                    <!--<input type="reset" value="Leeren" id="reset" name ="reset">-->
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="result"></div></td>    
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The script, that is placed inside form.php

```
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#ContactForm").submit(function(event) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $(this),
    a_betreff = $form.find('input[name="betreff"]').val(),
       a_name = $form.find('input[name="name"]').val(),
      a_email = $form.find('input[name="email"]').val(),
    a_telefon = $form.find('input[name="telefon"]').val(),
    a_nachricht2 = $form.find('textarea[name="nachricht2"]').val(),
    a_nachricht1 = $form.find('textarea[name="nachricht1"]').val(),
                    url = $form.attr('action');

    /* Send the data using post */
    var posting = $.post(url, {
        betreff: a_betreff,
        name: a_name,
        email: a_email,
        telefon: a_telefon,
        nachricht2: a_nachricht2,
        nachricht1: a_nachricht1,
    });

    /* Put the results in a div */
    posting.done(function(data) {
        var content = $(data).find('#content');
        $("#result").empty().append(content);
    });
});
```

And this is my contact.php

```
<?

// Assure that only via contact-form executable
if(!isset($_POST["submit"])){   
    exit;
}

// Returns true, if E-Mail is valid
function isValidEmail($email){ 
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false;
}

// Initialize Variables
$name = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]));
$email = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]));
$telefon = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST["telefon"]));
$telefon = strtolower($telefon);
$nachricht2 = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST["nachricht2"]));

$betreff = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST["betreff"]));
$nachricht1 = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST["nachricht1"]));

// Check if chatbot filled this input fields
if(($betreff != "") OR ($nachricht1 != "")){
    exit;
}

// Check if all required fields are field
if($name == ""){
    echo "Bitte Namen eingeben.";
    exit;
}

if($email == ""){
    echo "Bitte E-Mail eingeben.";
    exit;
}

if($nachricht2 == ""){
    echo "Bitte Nachricht eingeben.";
    exit;
}


$number = "/[0123456789]/";
if(preg_match($number, $name)) {
    echo "Der angegebene Name ist ung&uuml;ltig.";
    exit;
}

$digit = "/[a-z]/";
if(preg_match($digit, $telefon)) {
    echo "Die angegebene Telefonnummer ist ung&uuml;ltig.";
    exit;
}

if(!isValidEmail($email)){
    echo "Die angegebene E-Mail Adresse ist ung&uuml;ltig.";
    exit;
}

$message = "Guten Tag,\n\n";
$message .= "das Kontaktformular wurde am ".date("d.m.Y")." um ".date("H:i:s")." von:\n\nName: ".$name."\n";
$message .= "E-Mail: ".$email."\n";

if($telefon != ""){
    $message .= "Telefon: ".$telefon."\n";
}

$message .= "\nverwendet.\n\n";
$message .= "Die Nachricht lautet:\n'".$nachricht2."'";

if(mail("info@styledesign.de", "Nutzung des Kontaktformulars", $message)){
    echo "Vielen Dank f&uuml;r Ihre Nachricht. Sie werden in den n&auml;chsten Tagen eine Antwort erhalten.";
} else {
    echo "Es ist ein unerwarteter Fehler beim Versenden der E-Mail aufgetreten.";
}


?>
```

Well.. this does right now absolutely nothing, and I dont know why.
Can somebody tell me what exactly I need to fix because obviously I don't see it.

Comment: does data get submitted? (in the console view)

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: Could it be the space in the name attribute of the submit?

Your first if in the PHP checks if its set. It may think its not.

Comment: Where are you seeing the space @Chris?

Comment: On the "name" property/attribute of the <input type="submit"

Comment: Space between the attribute and the equals sign should be ok.

Comment: Okay just looked again, and you're not including the "submit" key in the data you are sending to the $.post, so it won't be set. And thus your PHP is exiting at the top

Comment: i added: a_submit = $form.find('input[name="submit"]').val(), but it still doesnt work.

Comment: If you remove the exit(); from that small "if" at the top, does it work? And, can you inspect the code from firebug or something to see if it really is calling the POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now here is a problem:

```
posting.done(function(data) {
  var content = $(data).find('#content');
  $("#result").empty().append(content);
});
```

Problem because you are passing the returned data as a jQuery selector string. Selector strings reference the existing DOM. So my guess is you want to do something like:

```
$("#result").empty().append(data);
```

Or if you are thinking of capturing a specific element from your returned string, try returning it either as JSON or XML, or use the [parseHTML()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) method.

**Edit**

That was Error number 1. Error number 2 is in your PHP file. You did:

```
if(!isset($_POST["submit"])){   
    exit;
}
```

Now you are submitting as AJAX, and you are actually submitting name-value pairs to your PHP script, not the form itself, so the submit button is not carried alongside your form. Take off that block of code.

Error Number 3 is the returned data. It is automatically interpreted by jQuery as HTML, and if you check your console after submitting the form, you will see `Syntax Error: Unrecognized expression ...` + whatever your PHP script echoed. To solve this, either take off this line:

```
var content = $(data).find('#content');
```

or use the [parseHTML()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) method I mentioned above:

```
var content = $($.parseHTML(data)).find('#content');
```

However, taking it off completely should be the best solution, because I don't really see its use there, given errors are actually echoed from your PHP script as plain strings and not HTML.

Comment: What did you exactly do? I replaced

"$("#result").empty().append(content);" with $("#result").empty().append(data); but it doesnt work.

Comment: Hey, @Sharivari check out the edit I did to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Although I didnt remove the check in the PHP file, it finally works!

Now I have one last problem, then it works how i want it to. I have a reset button and trigger it after i klick the send button with: $reset.click();

Do you maybe know how I can only reset it, if there was a mail send?

Comment: Okay, got it like this:

                    if(data == "Vielen Dank! Sie werden in den 1 - 3 Werktagen Tagen eine Antwort erhalten."){
                        /* Disable the button. */
                        $reset.click();
                    }